# How to send field value to initial value?

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have create a form and in the form field I have given a value 
and I want to send these field value to my initial value to `test2` object t1 field

```js
<FormiK
  initialValues={{
    test2: {
      t1:"",
      t2:"" ,                     
    },
  }}
  {({ values, }) => {
        return (
            <Form>
              <Field
                name="test2"
                value={values.test2}
                component={SelectComponent}
                options={[ "1", "2","3"]} 
               /> 
             </Form> 
</Formik>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Where is the `test1` object? Also, you need to specify what you want to achieve?

Comment: i want to send field value which i have set my field to set initial value and send it to backend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to send the field's values. you can use `onSubmit` method to send form fields.

```
<FormiK
  initialValues={
    test2: {
      t1:"",
      t2:""                      
           }
            }
 onSubmit={values => {console.log(values)}} // send to backend,call api,...

}
  {({ values, }) => {
        return (
            <Form>
              <Field
                name="test2"
                value={values.test2}
                component={SelectComponent}
                options={[ "1", "2","3"]} 
               /> 
             </Form> 
</Formik>
```